if two numerical sequence are equivalent , do they have the same sign from a certain rang n0
I am studying the convergence of a the numerical series  , $\sum {\sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right).x^n} $ at $x = 1$ ,  i thought of using the equivalence test that say that if two strictly positive numerical sequences are equivalent implies they have the same nature, however, the sign of $\sin\left(\frac {1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ can't be determined, despite that, it's equivalent (which is $\frac {1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is positive), can I say directly that this means that $\sin\left(\frac {1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ is positive from a certain rang and why?

You are wrong. That sign can be determined.

Yes you can! Indeed, if $a_n \sim b_n$, then $a_n = b_n + o(b_n)$. Let $N_0$ such that $\left|a_n - b_n\right| \le \frac12 b_n$ for $n\ge N_0$. Then for $n\ge N_0$, $a_n \ge \frac12 b_n$. If $b_n > 0$ then $a_n$ will be positive as well.

thank you so much !  , we can say that two functions are equivalent if the limite of the ratio is equal to 1 > 0 , which implies that the denominator and the numerator are of the same sign
